# Efficient way to insert a single records and ad-hoc bulk copies

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I am using parameterized query to insert single rows to a table.

```
    string commandText = @"INSERT INTO [DATA].[Jack].[Built] VALUES(
                                        @utcDT,
                                        @Symbol,
                                        @Type,
                                        @Value,
                                        @Size,
                                        @Mid,
                                        @Spread,
                                        @Date,
                                        @SeqNumber)";

    var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@utcDT", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Symbol", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Float);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mid", SqlDbType.Float);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Spread", SqlDbType.Float);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SeqNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);
```

Then call insert:

```
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@utcDT"].Value = utcDT;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = symbol;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Type"].Value = type;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Value"].Value = value;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Size"].Value = size;

                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Mid"].Value = current.Mid();
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Spread"].Value = current.Spread();
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = utcDT.Date;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@SeqNumber"].Value = fullSeqNumber;

                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, sometimes I want to insert millions of rows at once, this I do with SqlBulkCopy from a table. Which is very clean and simple.

But I do need to create a table first, again specifying all the columns and types.

Having to specify BOTH these things can be error prone. Is there a way to use a datatable WITHOUT SqlBulkCopy to insert single rows efficiently?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Single row inserts shouldn't be hurting performance by using ExecuteNonQuery. If you have to build the table in both cases, why would bulk copy vs execute non query make a difference? What am I missing?

Comment: Technically, `SqlBulkCopy` does not require a table; it can take its rows from an `IDataReader` implementation, which has far less memory overhead (possibly close to zero, if the rows are streamed). However, even building a `DataTable` with the correct column names and types could be done simply be enumerating your `SqlParameter` collection. Build a prototype command (or table) once and use that for the rest.

Comment: Single insert using Insert command and parameterisation is very fast. BulkCopy is very fast for larger tables. But I have read that using BulkCopy for a single row at a time is slow. CUrrently I do both, but it means that whenever I change the column spec I need to rewrite the parametersisation set-up AND the datatable set-up.

Comment: @ManInMoon is the single record insert user facing? If not, why care that much about speed. Optimize for the bulk operation imo. Perhaps you could provide the code you are using for the bulk insert.

Comment: These sound like vastly dissimilar workflows, so I'd almost say managing them separately might not be a bad idea. Alternatively, you could create a stored procedure which accepts a table-valued parameter with columns that match the variables you're using right now. Then you can pas as many rows to that proc/TVP as you want, and handle them in the same place. I don't know that I would go that route with MILLIONS of rows, but it's an alternative.